# Drupal publishing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a Drupal website. It has been designed by someone else. 
I want to change the settings from automatically publishing post to not automatically publishing. I set the option in content types, my content type (edit), publishing options. It is set to "not published". Every time I add a new post, it still is published though.

Where is this going wrong? Do I need to change something in the code? if yes, where do I change it?

Comment: Does the site have any custom modules? If so that would be the first place I would look, specifically a function like *_form_alter().

Comment: there are indeed a number of custom modules. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: i think the answer is in Override node options

Comment: There a plenty areas where it could be being overridden, the obvious places to look are in hook_form_alter(), hook_node_presave() or hook_node_insert(). Other modules could be doing it, such as the Rules module or like you say the Override Node Options module.

Comment: could i change it in function products_add(){
        global $user;
        $products = create('products');
        return drupal_get_form('products_form', $products);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of configuration options that could cause this that can be adjusted via the user interface without delving into code.

It's possible that anonymous users have permissions to view unpublished content.

It's also possible that you have a views configured to return results unfiltered by published = true.